# Android Accessibility, how to remove all Button Actions?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, xamarin, accessibility

On Android, TalkBack announces "Double tap to activate, double tap and hold to long press".
How can I remove all these default actions and just have it say nothing?

*While ignoring whether that is a good idea or not for now.*

**Update** the below code seems to not do anything:

```
    private class NoActionsAccessibilityDelegate : View.AccessibilityDelegate
    {
        public override void OnInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(View host, Android.Views.Accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo info)
        {
            base.OnInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info);
            foreach (var action in info.ActionList.ToList()) //to list ensures we are not iterating while modifying the readonly ActionList property
            {
                info.RemoveAction(action);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you cannot do that. Developers will not have control over the system services. Just think how will users who need accessibility use your app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your 'view' does not have a click action but for some reason the system detects it as clickable, use the following, (I am using Xamarin for my implementation and the code to disable actions is as follows):

```
myView.Clickable = false;
myView.LongClickable = false;
```

Yes that will disable interaction with the view, but in my case the view is not meant to be interactable to begin with. For some reason the system thinks it has an action though it does not.